# How to display the regular price in the order items table in the admin

Tags: woocommerce

This is the sale price that is displayed (excluding the VAT) in addition to the quantity and the total price and the VAT, for each item in the order items table.

I would like to display the `regular price` and the `discount` of the product item.

I checked in the `WC_Order_Item_Product`, but I could not find the information and I do not want to retrieve it from the related product attributes because that information can change.

I want the information that was active when the order was created.
I searched on this site and and googled a lot but could find any information. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Nobody can help ?

Comment: Still no idea ? I pretty sure someone can help this simple question. No ?